# Servlet passes value to jsp on reload or new window

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page and a servlet that process a checkbox form. I want the form to retain the last value even in a new session. If the page reloads or a new window is opened, I want the data to be stored.

JSP:

```
<html><body>
<p>
<form name="checkboxes" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Servlet" method="post">
<%  if(getServletContext().getAttribute("test").equals("on")) { %>
<input type=checkbox name="test" checked>Test
<%  } else { %>
        <input type=checkbox name="test" >Test
<% } %>
       <input type="submit" value="submit"">
       <%= getServletContext().getAttribute("test") %>
</form>
</p>
```

Servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
@WebServlet("/Servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet
{
  private String c4;
  public void init() 
  { 
      c4 = "";
  } 

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      String c1 = request.getParameter("test");
      ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
      if(c1!=null) {
          System.out.println("c1 " + c1);
          context.setAttribute("test", "on");
      }
      else {
          context.setAttribute("test", "off");
      }
      request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);


}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    doPost(request,response);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want the form to retain the last value even in a new session. If the
>   page reloads or a new window is opened, I want the data to be stored.

There are two options that you can choose:

(1) Save the last value in an **in-memory cache** store and retrieve it again when the request comes.

(2) Save the last value in a **persistent store** (preferably database) and retrieve it again when the request comes.